# PHP - SoapClient::SoapClient failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php, .net, soap, integration

I'm trying to integrate a PHP portal with a CRM(microsoft dynamics .NET) system using SOAP.

This is part of my code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://XX.XXX.X.XX:5050/host.svc?wsdl");
```

This line returns 2 errors

```
Warninig: Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://80.248.5.35:5050/host.svc?wsdl): failed to open stream: Connection refused

 Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load   from 'http://XX.XXX.X.XX:5050/host.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity
```

Opening the link in the browser works and running this code in my local machine(localhost) works also. 
i've tried `file_get_contents("http://XX.XXX.X.XX:5050/host.svc?wsdl");` but this returns a warning message

```
Message: file_get_contents(http://80.248.5.35:5050/host.svc?wsdl): failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

i've tried so many solutions from stackoverflow. 
If anyone could help me with this or shed more light on the situation cause this is my first attempt at something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

My webserver was denying me from making outgoing connection through any port rather than the default port. i fixed it by changing the web service to the default port on the ISS

Answer (score 0):

I've been frustrated by this "failed to open stream" error too, but from the point of view of trying to connect to a web service from the web.

However, the issue is the same underneath: your web server needs to be able to reach the web service from itself.

My solution if you are using a **Windows** Server: add an entry to your windows host file to allow loopback on the server for the external domain you're using for the web service.

So, open your "hosts" file, which is usually in somewhere like C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. Then add a line like:
`<machine LAN IP like 192.168.1.1 or 127.0.0.1> <domain.ofwebsevice.com>`

Comment: Thanks for contributing to an old unanswered question. This could benefit other people in the future. Would you mind rephrase the usages of the word "server" to make them more specific to which server you're referring to (like you did when you said "web server")? This should improve clarity of the answer IMHO.

Comment: @Ricardo: yes good point and thanks. Have attempted to clarify....